# Are there any natural lakes within 3-hours of Dallas?

Tags: usa, water-sports, geography, lakes

I became engaged in a debate at work and I'm trying to track down an answer to the following: are there any natural (not man-made) lakes within a 3-hour drive of Dallas Texas?

Keep in mind that this would also include parts of Oklahoma and the Red River. Surely there must be at least 1 natural lake in that radius . . . right?

Comment: @gerrit Is this a serious comment? Three hours in a car is a LONG distance and when you turn into a radius, that is A LOT of land area. No lakes in that much area would be quite a feat.

Comment: @UnknownCoder Questions on this site are supposed to be for *practical* questions about travel, so I think the objection is the arbitrariness of the radius you've set where a particular geologic/hydrologic feature *must* exist. Are there snowcapped peaks within three hours of Dallas? Ocean beaches? And why three hours? Even one hour in a car is a "long" distance at Texas speed limits and by East Coast standards. :-)

Comment: @UnknownCoder Yes, it is. Natural lakes require a particular climate and geography.  It's entirely conceivable that a region with a 500 km diameter has no place where those conditions are met.

Answer (score 3):

[Roebuck Lake](http://staging.waymarking.com/waymarks/WMFQNP_Roebuck_Lake_Oklahoma_USA), an oxbow lake off the Red River, ought to qualify.